# analyzed field vs doc_values: true field

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an elasticsearch that contains over half a billion documents that each have a url field that stores a URL.

The url field mapping currently has the settings:

```
{
    index: not_analyzed
    doc_values: true
    ...
}
```

We want our users to be able to search URLs, or portions of URLs without having to use wildcards.
For example, taking the URL with path: `/part1/user@site/part2/part3.ext`

They should be able to bring back a matching document by searching:

- `part3.ext`
- `user@site`
- `part1`
- `part2/part3.ext`

The way I see it, we have two options:

1. Implement an analysed version of this field (which can no longer have `doc_values: true`) and do match querying instead of wildcards. This would also require using a custom analyser to leverage the pattern tokeniser to make the extracted terms correct (the standard tokeniser would split `user@site` into `user` and `site`).
2. Go through our database and for each document create a new field that is a list of URL parts. This field could have `doc_values: true` still so would be stored off-heap, and we could do term querying on exact field values instead of wildcards.

**My question is this:**

Which is better for performance: having a list of variable lengths that has `doc_values` on, or having an analysed field? (ie: option 1 or option 2) OR is there an option 3 that would be even better yet?!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that no-one has actually performance tested the two options, so I did.

I took a sample of 10 million documents and created two new indices:

1. An index with an analysed field that was setup as suggested in the other answer.
2. An index with a `string` field that would store all permutations of URL segmentation.

I ran an enrichment process over the second index to populate the fields. The field values on the first index were created when I re-indexed the sample data from my main index.

Then I created a set of gatling tests to run against the indices and compared the gatling results and netdata (https://github.com/firehol/netdata) landscape for each.

The results were as follows:

[image: Quantile Comparisons of analysed vs not analysed list]

Regarding the netadata landscape: The analysed field showed a spike - although only a small one - on all elastic nodes. The not_analysed list field tests didn't even register.

It is worth mentioning that enriching the list field with URL segmentation permutations bloated the index by about 80% in our case. So there's a trade off - you never need to do wildcard searches for exact sub-segment matching on URLs, but you'll need a lot more disk to do it.

## Update

Don't do this. Go for doc_values. Doing anything with analyzed strings that have a massive number of possible terms will mean massive field data that will, eventually, never fit in the amount of memory you can allocate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about a field where you need doc_values but can not index with keyword-analyzer.

You did not mention why you need [doc_values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/doc-values.html). But you did mention that you currently not search in this field.
So I guess that the name of the search-field do not have to be the same: you can [copy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) the field value in an other field which is only for search ( "store": false ). For this new field you can use the [pattern-analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html) or [pattern-tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html) for your use case.

Comment: This seems like a good solution! I'm going to test it this week. If all goes well, and it performs nicely I'll accept the answer. Quick question as a follow up - do I need to re-index my data for it to take effect?